# All sites (SO, meta, SF, SU etc' Stack Exchange) aggregator?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange

This might have been suggested before but what the hell

My idea is to have a sort of main "aggregator" site that collects question from all of the sites in the network. Say I am active in SO and meta and in three odd Stack Exchange sites. Instead of having to visit each site in turn, I want to see questions from all of the sites in a single place page.

If we look at how reddit does this, there are the various sub-reddits, these are the different questions sites and there is the main site which a logged in user sees when he goes to `www.reddit.com` which includes articles from all subreddits the user is registered to.

I think this will help especially small Stack Exchange sites that have trouble generating their own stand alone traffic. If I'll see questions from "Game Development" in my aggregated page, I am much more likely to pick it up.

What do you think?

Comment: It's called the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stack aggregation ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29382/stack-aggregation)

Answer (score 7):

You can aggregate question from multiple site from the http://stackexchange.com website (tagged question section). You just need to select which tag or sites you want to follow and it will aggregate them on that page.

Comment: Ow, FGITWed by 16 seconds! +1

Answer (score 0):

This already exists: click on that StackExchange icon in the left upper corner of this page...